# Neuron results are a little off

Tags: java, neural-network

Hi I coded a single neuron to predict a student's mark for subject D based of the marks they got for subject A, B and C.

After training my neuron with some historical data that contain the 3 marks as well as the actual mark they got for subject D, I then inputed test data to see how closely the predicted mark would match with the actual one.
Below is my Neuron class

```
public class Neuron
{
    double[] Weights = new double[3];

    public Neuron(double W1, double W2, double W3)
    {
        Weights[0] = W1;
        Weights[1] = W2;
        Weights[2] = W3;
    }

    public double FnetLinear(int Z1, int Z2, int Z3)
    {
        return (Z1*Weights[0] + Z2*Weights[1] + Z3*Weights[2]);
    }

    public void UpdateWeight(int i, double Wi)
    {
        Weights[i] = Wi;
    }
}
```

And here is my main class

```
public class Main
{
    public int t;
    public Neuron neuron;
    double LearningRate = 0.00001;
    public ArrayList<Marks> TrainingSet, TestSet;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        TrainingSet = ReadCSV("G:\\EVOS\\EVO_Assignemnt1\\resources\\Streamdata.csv");
        TestSet =  ReadCSV("G:\\EVOS\\EVO_Assignemnt1\\resources\\Test.csv");
        Random ran = new Random();
        neuron = new Neuron(ran.nextDouble(), ran.nextDouble(), ran.nextDouble());
        train();
        Test();
    }


    public void train()
    {
        t = 0;
        while(t<1000000)
        {
            for(Marks mark: TrainingSet)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<neuron.Weights.length; i++)
                {
                    double yp = neuron.FnetLinear(mark.marks[0] , mark.marks[1], mark.marks[2]);
                    double wi = neuron.Weights[i] - LearningRate*(-2*(mark.marks[3]-yp))*mark.marks[i];
                    neuron.UpdateWeight(i, wi);
                }
            }
            t++;
        }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        System.out.println("Test Set results:");
        int count = 1;

        for(Marks mark: TestSet)
        {
            double fnet = neuron.FnetLinear(mark.marks[0] , mark.marks[1], mark.marks[2]);
            System.out.println("Mark " + count + ": " + fnet);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Marks> ReadCSV(String csv)
    {
        ArrayList<Marks> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        BufferedReader br;
        try
        {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] n = line.split(",");
                Marks stud = new Marks(Integer.valueOf(n[0]), Integer.valueOf(n[1]), Integer.valueOf(n[2]), Integer.valueOf(n[3]));
                temp.add(stud);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

This is the test data with the last number being the actual mark.
[image]

After running the test data i get results around these:
[image]

As you can see the first 4 marks predictions are way off from the actual mark.
I followed the text book's explenation of Computational Intlligence An Introduction (Chapter 2 if u are curious).

However I would like to know what I im doing wrong. How can I get more accurate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural networks are very black-box esque; Due to this, it's pretty hard to say exactly why your marks results are way off.

That being said, here are some of the main methods of increasing the accuracy of your neural network:

- **Adjust the number of layers and neurons**; I notice you're only using a single neuron. A single neuron in a neural *network* is typically just... bad. You're never going to get any good results like that. Neural networks need enough complexity in the form of layering and neuron count in order to calculate or predict whatever it is you're trying to teach it to do. A single neuron by itself really can't learn anything useful. **This is also probably a big reason why your network accuracy is so bad.**
- **Train for longer**; I notice you're only training your network 1 million times; this is not always enough. For reference, the last time I trained a neural network, I used over 30 million sets of input/output.
- **Retrain your network with different starting weights**; Randomized starting weights are great, but sometimes you just get a bad batch of starting weights. In the same project where I used 30 million input/output sets, I also tried over 25 different configurations of initial starting weights across 15 different layouts of nodes and layers.
- **Pick a different activation function**; Linear activation functions are usually not that useful. I usually default to using a sigmoid function to start off, unless there are specific other functions that fulfill the use case I'm trying to train.

A common pitfall that can cause low accuracy is **bad training data**; Make sure the training data you're using is correct and is internally consistent with whatever it is you're trying to teach.

As a final note, I find myself having some trouble understanding what kind of a neural network you're trying to write exactly; I've made the assumption that this is some sort of attempt at a feed forward, back propagation neural network with a single neuron in it, but most of the advice here should still apply.

Comment: Seems like it is just bad data. Thanks.